# Who in the company has the authority to fire someone?

Tags: ethics, standards, dismissal

Who has the right to announce the dismissal from work to an employee? If you're a small company of about 20 people and there's a certain hierarchy, does the CEO have to be the one that announces the employee that he is fired, or does the CEO only have to sign the paper and any other person that was superior to that employee can be the one to officially tell him that?

Comment: Do you have a specific concerns here? If you're the one doing the firing and don't know this, pay for an external HR consultant so you don't get it wrong. If you're the one being fired, this isn't the line to take.

Comment: I may soon be some sort of a direct manager to a new employee and I may be the one to decide if they're good or not because the other staff have no capability to asses the performance on this field of work.

Comment: One point, set aside the idea of making an *announcement* to the *other* staff that someone is fired.

Comment: @Kilisi The title does not seem to reflect the question any more. The OP did *not* ask who has the *authority to fire*, but whether *announcing the firing* has to be done by a specific person.

Comment: @sermonionx Your ability to perform an assessment on someone is orthogonal to your ability to fire someone.

Comment: Any person could *announce* a dismissal. Whether they have the right, or the apparent authority, to bind the company to that announcement could be a very complex legal matter, depending on exactly what basis there is for any dispute.

Comment: Does your company not have a process for discipline procedures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By coincidence, I read a story on a totally different website that went like this: Employee is on holiday in a different country. He receives a call from his manager, who asks why he isn't at work. Employee says "because I'm on holiday". Manager says "Come to work immediately". Employee says "I'm abroad, and I'm on holiday. I'll be back on day X". Manager says "You are fired".

So far, so bad. Manager hadn't noticed that he had started a conference call, and *his* boss was in the call. The boss called the employee and told him he wasn't fired. When the employee returned back from holiday, the manager's desk was empty.

So just because someone tells you that you are fired doesn't mean you are fired. It's very likely that the company wants to fire you, because people like this manager are very, very rare. But you would first contact HR or someone above the person telling you, to make sure the company does actually want to fire you. And then they have to follow whatever the laws in your country and/or your contract say about getting laid off.

It is quite likely that your direct manager is not authorized by the company to fire people. On the other hand, it wouldn't be uncommon that he or she could tell their manager why they think you should be fired, and someone with the right authorisation will listen to them.

And if the company doesn't follow the laws, that will not ultimately save your job, but it can put extra money in your pocket - for example if the company has to give you four weeks notice by law, and they fire you without notice and without a good reason for that, you are not fired. They'll have to pay until they figure it out and give you notice, plus four weeks notice after that. That would be a deserved punishment for their incompetence.

PS. After reading Sermonion's comment: Check with your boss whether you are authorized to fire people. Or whether you are authorized to decide that someone should be fired, but someone else has to actually do it; that's the more likely case. And the actual firing would be done by someone who was trained and knows how to do everything by the law, which is most likely not you.

Comment: _"..which is most likely not you"_ reading the OP's question it seems like it - maybe he's more in the position to **suggest** if someone is in for the long run or should be let go within the probation period..

Answer (score 13):

Anyone can make that announcement, as long as it's officially sanctioned by upper management and assuming that's the way upper management wants it done.

The person transmitting the message doesn't need to be high-ranking at all.

HR, the receptionist, the security guard, IT services, a messenger service, etc. In the US, we even hire outside consultants to do our layoffs/firings for us. And in many cases, for security reasons, our access to the office network and our RFID badges are disabled before we're actually notified of the dismissal itself.

Answer (score 4):

From a formal perspective, the dismissal is issued by the company, not an individual person, since it dissolves the work contract, which is also between the company and the employee.

So the requirement is that the company communicates their intent in the legally required way, which is locale specific, but usually along the lines of "in writing, delivered to the employee."

In any larger company, you'd use registered mail for that to have proof of delivery, but handing over the letter with a witness is also common. There are pretty much no requirements who is present there, typically it will be any of the superiors and an HR representative.

An instruction to "clean out your desk and go home" is not a formal dismissal, but a change in job scope, and that can be ordered by any superior, but would typically go through your direct manager. That has no legal effect on your employment contract, only the letter does, but that is a technicality.

Comment: Of course if the company forgets that "formality", then you are still employed and not given notice, and if you are a salaried employee, they have to pay your full salary for sitting at home and doing nothing. On the other hand, it happened to me and probably many others who were told "take everything home from your desk that you need to work, and go home" with the expectation that I'm working from home.

Answer (score 2):

It can be any person the employer trusts to do it.

It might not be a person at all.

You could get a letter in the mail. You might get a letter in the mail *in addition* to a trusted employee telling you, so the mail service acts as proof that you have received it by a certain day, in case you deny it and it gets a he-said-she-said situation.